# Conjure-up with Openstack NovaLXD installation doesnt work

Tags: conjure-up

I'm trying to install Openstack NovaLXD with Conjure-up. Unfortunately, the installation fails every time..

My setup is the following:

Virtual Machine (Virtual Box)
Ubuntu 16.4.3 LTS
juju 2.2.3-xenial-amd64
conjure-up 2.3.1 (sudo snap install conjure-up --classic)

Before I started conjure-up I configured lxdbr1 (sudo snap install lxd) and a zfs pool (sudo apt install zfsutils-linux) with 30GB. The bridge interface is configured and the zfs pool (sudo zpool list) shows me HEALTH status ONLINE.

After starting conjure-up I get the following message when I want to deploy all the 15 applications :

Oops, there was a problem with your install:
Reason: Unable to bootstrap (cloud type: localhost)
Review log messages at ~/.cache/conjure-up/conjure-up.log If appropriate, please submit a bug here: https://github.com/conjure-up/conjure-up/issues/new

I have no idea what is wrong... :(

the logfile shows an error : conjure-up/openstack-novalxd - provider.py:376 - Unable to parse JSON output from LXD

Comment: the logfile shows an error : conjure-up/openstack-novalxd - provider.py:376 - Unable to parse JSON output from LXD

Answer (score 0):

I have come across similar challenge but with Parallels Desktop (similar in functionality to your virtual box) on my laptop. In my case problem existed with following setup:

- Parallels Desktop running fresh install of ubuntu-16.04.3-server-amd64.iso, + conjure-up --classic
- WiFi connection;
- virtual network set as "**Bridged Network (Default adapter)**"

To resolve my problem I have changed network settings to "**Shared Network**" for this virtual and it works fine. In Virtual box I think this will be NAT or NAT network. 
I am also planning on testing it with physical connection to see if i can replicate this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I confirm that this still happens with Ubuntu 16.04.03 on VirtualBox 5.2.6 r120293 on MacOS (latest setup at the time of writing) if you have 2 NICs:

1. a NAT for outgoing connections;
2. a "Host only" to SSH into the virtual machine.

"jujud machine" hangs using all the CPUs and up to 35% of the memory. High mongodb utilization too and all the LXD containers hung on "waiting for machine".

Removing "Host only" interfaces unblocks the installer.
This is seriously flawed.

Comment: By the way, the installer timeouts after 45 minutes or so. A lot of components stall in "waiting for machine" and after the installer crashes all the containers are left over.